# Could not find a required file. Name: index.html

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

I have been working on this React project, since a few months without having come across this error. I haven't made any changes in the location of the index.html file in the project tree, which is why I can't explain this error.

I have tried the following measures without success:

1. changing the location of public folder
2. changing the location of contents of public folder
3. changing the location of package-lock.json
4. changing the location of package.json
5. npm install
6. npm install react-scripts --save

Please find the error displayed in the terminal:

```
Could not find a required file.  
Name: index.html  
Searched in: /Users/Sujay/Documents/Documents/Learn Web Development the Hard Way/lacapsule/project/Dark Sky Map Bitbucket/darkskymap_frontend/public  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
npm ERR! errno 1  
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`  
npm ERR! Exit status 1  
npm ERR!   
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.  
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Sujay/.npm/_logs/2019-08-06T07_12_22_366Z-debug.log

Expected result : React project should launch without any issue.   
Actual result: Error message in terminal mentioned above.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### index.html has been moved/removed from the /public directory

Does your project have an index.html file in the public directory?

If not you can get the one that [Create React App uses here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template/template/public/index.html)

It should be in `<your project root>/public/index.html`

---

If you are using Git for version control it will be able to tell you if something was moved or removed.

Run `git status` to view changed files

Comment: Hello Jonathan, Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. My index.html file is indeed in the public directory. I had created the project with Create React App so I haven't altered the location of index.html which is still in the public folder. I use git for version control and I have checked my preceding commits. None of them involve changing the location of index.html. Moreover my colleagues have no problem launching the project with npm start. I have probably moved something without realising it but cannot figure out what.

Comment: I think I will just delete the project and clone it from the origin repository. But this breaks the links with distant repos which is always a delicate thing to do. I am upvoting your anwser but not the check mark because my problem hasn't been solved yet. My upvote hasn't been taken into account because my reputation is below 15.

Comment: You were right. The public folder was misplace. It was erroneously moved into the src folder instead of being at the root of the project.

Comment: It's so stupid that react works this way. Angular just recreates anything you delete in the public folder.

Answer (score 2):

Your public folder might be missing, just create another app using create-react-app and copy paste the ***public*** folder in this directory

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my MERN stack app. I have three folders in my project root: client, admin and api. Current folder structure is ```[project root]/public/index.html```. App works fine when index.html is saved this way. When I move my public folder into the client folder and run ```npm start```  I get "Can't find file. Name: index.html. Searched in public" . How should I save my index.html file so that it doesn't throw that error and both the frontend and backend of my app runs properly? My package.json file is in the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. Both my package-lock and package.json were outside of the root folder. Once I moved them into the root folder it started up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have accidentally deleted the public directory so it couldn't find the index.html file

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here in case you had the same issue as me and your index.html file is exactly where you want it and where you told app engine.

Add package.json to your .glcoudignore file at the root level of your project.

I had a tonne of issues with this and my exact setup had previously worked so I'm not sure what the issue was.

I'm using create-react-app (CRA) and my app.yaml file looks like this:

```
runtime: nodejs16
handlers:
# Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\..+)$
# Catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

With CRA `npm run build` will build the project to a /build directory and place index.html inside it.

That app.yaml file should point at it and everything should be grand.

The issue though was that app engine will try and run `npm start` if it's in your package.json file. Changing the script name to `dev` instead of `start` still didn't work when I tried to deploy and instead I just had to include `package.json` in my `.gcloudignore` file.

This is a pain because it just means that I have to build the app before deploying always. But this is how I was able to get this to work after spending hours looking into the issue.