# Task to build react files with Azure Devops from Azure Repos

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have created a pipeline to build a folder with react files.
Unfortunately I am unable to perform the "npm run build" coomand.
I tried creating a custom npm task and i put inside it the command "npm run build" but it does not accept it.
Here is the image of my CI pipeline.[image]

Any hint on how to achieve the build task?

here is the yaml that gets generated by the npm custom task :[image]

[image]

Comment: a config file would be much helpful to understand. So far we only see what you get as *output* but not your *input*...

Comment: What do you mean by config file. In the picture I put the stages of my pipeline. Now, I attach also the yaml resulting from the npm custom task

Comment: I managed to create the build task but now I am getting the error attached in the last image. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an index.html file in the public folder. Could you build your project successfully on your local machine. I found this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371035/could-not-find-a-required-file-name-index-html).