# React app "could not find a index.html file"

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app and `npm start` doesn't work.

I'm trying to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` but I get these errors again.

```
Could not find a required file.
Name: index.html
 Searched in: C:\Users\avihai\Desktop\projects\super-market\public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! super-market@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the super-market@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\avihai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-08T16_32_26_415Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you running this command from your project root directory? Do you have index.html file in your public folder?

Comment: yes i run it from my root directory and no i didnt have a index.html file in my public

Comment: i change the project name and the directory name maybe this is the problam?

Comment: If you are not using other build frameworks like netxjs react apps need index.html file in your public folder. Can you share your folder structure package.json file?

Comment: i have index.js and i try to move him to public folder but i get the same errors

Comment: can you show me your project structure and package.json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a required file. Name: index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371035/could-not-find-a-required-file-name-index-html)