# Encountered this error wile trying to host my project on Vercel by importing my code from Github

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, frontend, vercel

What should I do to resolve this warning, I'm a self taught Front end developer and I'm currently trying to create and host my first web page using react

```
Cloning gitohub.com/Passion94/React-Apps (Branch: main, Commit: da89a2a)
Cloning completed: 729.612ms
Looking up build cache...
Build Cache not found
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.4.12-05a80a4
Installing dependencies...
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
added 1462 packages in 36s
224 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
Running "npm run build"
> my-app@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /vercel/path0/public
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I have not tried any solution, Cant find anything on Google

Comment: `gitohub.com`? Really?

Comment: Does `npm run build` execute cleanly on your local machine? What does that command look like in your _package.json_?

Comment: Have you reviewed this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57371378/1024832

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svgo package is a Node.js module for optimizing SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) files. It is often used in web development to optimize SVG images for faster loading and better performance.

To upgrade to the latest version of the svgo package, you can run the following command in your terminal
npm install svgo@latest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).